# breezeJS: what is a resource? are there multiple kinds of resources?

Tags: javascript, breeze

I am attempting to add the breezeJS library to my Angular project. I am confused with regards to breeze's resources:

Looking at the API I see that the `MetaDataStore` has a method `getEntityTypeNameForResourceName` which I assume returns a proper entity type name from a "resource name" which I assume is a nickname one can give to entity. I am thinking it operates something like:

```
metaStore.getEntityTypeNameForResourceName('users') // returns USR where USR is the table name in the db
```

However further in the API docs I see the SaveOptions object with takes an optional [resourceName] parameter in its constructor. I assume this is the service URL or controller method that is to handle the save?

Are these two different kinds of "resources" and are my interpretations correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of the same, sort of different.

### Query Resource Name

The `getEntityTypeNameForResourceName('users')` reveals the `EntityType` name associated with the **query resource name**, 'users'. In your case the `EntityType` name is 'USR' which I'm betting is the name of the class *on the server* as well as the name of the `EntityType` *on the client*.

I don't know how you created your metadata so I can't be sure how the 'users' resource name came to be. If you generated metadata from an EF `DbContext` it is probable that the query resource name 'users' matches the name of the corresponding `DbSet`. That's what Breeze-on-.NET assumes.

I'm guessing also that you query for users with an expression kind of like this:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('users') ...
```

The `'users'` parameter is what we call the "query resource name" in breeze. Because most folks only ever provide a "query resource name", we tend to just say "resource name".

The corresponding server-side resource from an HTTP perspective is the concatenation of the breeze *dataServiceName* and this "resource name". If you created your `EntityManager` with the dataServiceName "api", then the HTTP resource is `~/api/users`.

A query can also be directed at the cache. You can get all users in cache with

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from('users').using(manager).executeLocally();
```

What if you wanted to use the `EntityType` name to fetch from cache like this?

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from('USR').using(manager).executeLocally(); // fails
```

That won't work because you haven't said that the `EntityType` name is also a query resource name. You *could* make it an alternate resource name by registering it with metadata.

```
metaStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName ( 'USR', 'USR'); // resourceName, entityTypeName
metaStore.getEntityTypeNameForResourceName('USR'); // returns 'USR'
breeze.EntityQuery.from('USR').using(manager).executeLocally(); // now it works
```

This returns cached users too :-)

```
metaStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName ( 'Foo', 'USR' ); // resourceName, entityTypeName
metaStore.getEntityTypeNameForResourceName('Foo'); // returns 'USR'
breeze.EntityQuery.from('Foo').using(manager).executeLocally();
```

### Save Resource Name

By default, the Breeze `EntityManager.saveChanges` method POSTs the change-set payload to the *dataServiceName* + "SaveChanges" endpoint (e.g. `~/api/SaveChanges`)

The presumption is that your server-side web api controller accepts POST requests to that URL and implements the breeze "SaveChanges" protocol. The breeze-on-.NET `EntityContextProvider` exposes this method and observes that protocol and most people wire that method to their breeze controller's `SaveChanges` method.

The word "SaveChanges" is the **default** ***save resource name***. Very few developers think about this nor should they unless they need multiple endpoints for saving entity changes.

You can establish an alternative save endpoint by designating an alternative save resource name. For example

```
var saveOptions = new breeze.SaveOptions({resourceName: 'SpecialSave'});
manager.saveChanges(null, saveOptions); // save all pending changes to ~/api/SpecialSave
```

In this case, you're expecting your server-side web api controller to implement a `SpecialSave` method with special logic for your use case.

Why might you do this? Perhaps you will write guard logic on the server in the `SaveChanges` method to refuse changes to users, delegating that task exclusively to this `SpecialSave` method which is protected by appropriate authorization rules.

You can write as many of these alternative save endpoints as you need.

### Summary

There clearly are two kinds of breeze resource names - query and save. They differ in their purpose. They are similar in that they cause the `EntityManager` to send HTTP requests to a URL that is the concatenation of the *dataServiceName* and the resource name.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Very helpful. Just one follow up question: I am actually using Node/Sequelize back-end. I have yet to generate my meta-data and I was only using 'USR' as an illustration, I don't really have an EntityType yet. In my case the EntityType name USR would come from the breeze-sequelize generated model, (ultimately coming from the db table name), correct? Also any recommendations on how I can auto-generate an ODATA abiding metadata file from a posgress db?